# create sine wave audio with as3 - sweep up and down frequency

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I'm making sinewave sound with AS3 using SampleDataEvent. I can make a pure sinewave easily enough, but if i try to sweep through frequencies i get horrible popping. Here's the code i'm using - any help would be great.

```
    package
    {
        import flash.display.*;
        import flash.events.*;
        import flash.media.*;
        import flash.utils.Timer;

        public class DynamicSound extends Sprite
        {
            private var sound:Sound;
            private var noise:Number = 0;
            private var f:Number = 1000;
            private var v:Number = 1;
            private var sweepDown:Boolean = true;

            // make the sound
            public function DynamicSound():void
            {
                sound = new Sound();
                sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onCallback);
                sound.play();
                sweep();
            }

            // create the sinewave
            private function onCallback(e:SampleDataEvent):void
            {
                for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
                {
                    noise += 1;
                    var sampleNumber = noise;
                    e.data.writeFloat(v * Math.sin(sampleNumber * f / 44100));
                    e.data.writeFloat(v * Math.sin(sampleNumber * f / 44100));

                }
            }

            // sweep up and down frequency
            private function sweep() {
                var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
                timer.start();
                function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
                {
                    if(sweepDown){
                        f--;
                    } else {
                        f++;
                    }
                    if (f <=600 ){
                        sweepDown = false;
                    }
                    if (f >= 1000) {
                        sweepDown = true;
                    }
                trace(f);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the fault is with the approach, the sweep needs to be gradual, when you step it like that you create an abrupt change in the sound wave, which is interpreted as a short high-frequency signal - a pop or click. The way I'd recommend you do this modulation would be inside the callback loop.

set a destination freq (`dF`) and a current frequency(`cF`), and instead of doing an abrupt change set `cF = cF*0.8 + dF*0.2` inside the loop, this should remove the abrupt change and have it happen over several samples.

Answer (score 0):

```
//When the frequency changes, the phase will also change. 
//By adjusting the phase, there will no longer be horrible popping.

//This will solve the problem:

var f_old:Number = f;                    
noise=noise*f_old/f;  f_old=f; 


//Copy/paste in the first frame of the main timeline:

          import flash.display.*;
          import flash.events.*;
          import flash.media.*;
          import flash.utils.Timer;

              var sound:Sound;
              var noise:Number = 0;
              var f:Number = 1000;
              var v:Number = 1;
              var sweepDown:Boolean = true;
var f_old:Number = f;

                  // make the sound
                  sound = new Sound();
                  sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onCallback);
                  sound.play();
                  sweep();

              // create the sinewave
              function onCallback(e:SampleDataEvent):void
              {
                  for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
                  {
                      noise += 1;
                      var sampleNumber = noise;
                      e.data.writeFloat(v * Math.sin(sampleNumber * f / 44100));
                      e.data.writeFloat(v * Math.sin(sampleNumber * f / 44100));

                  }
              }

              // sweep up and down frequency
              function sweep() {
                  var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);
                  timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
                  timer.start();
                  function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
                  {
                      if(sweepDown){
                          f--;
                      } else {
                          f++;
                      }
                      if (f <=600 ){
                          sweepDown = false;
                      }
                      if (f >= 1000) {
                          sweepDown = true;
                      }
                  trace(f);

//Keep the instantaneous value at the same level:
noise=noise*f_old/f;
f_old=f;

                  }
              }         

//Explanation:
//The instantaneous value of the wave must not change at the moment of frequency change. 
//In this script the instantaneous value is determined by:  
//v * Math.sin(sampleNumber * f / 44100)
//noise = sampleNumber  →  v * Math.sin(sampleNumber * f / 44100) = v * Math.sin(noise * f / 44100)
//Keep the instantaneous value at the same level:
//v * Math.sin(noise_new * f / 44100) = v * Math.sin(noise* f_old / 44100) 
//Cancel out v*Math.sin and /44100   →
//noise_new * f = noise* f_old  →  noise_new = noise*f_old/f
//Because noise gets a new value, there is no need to give noise the name noise_new.  →
//noise = noise*f_old/f
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome, Your answer might be correct but please explain your code.

Comment: hi :) you can edit your answer to post the explanation